# Syntactic correctness of a function

Tags: haskell

Here is a definition of a function:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Can you guys explain what it means exactly? The thing I don't understand are `f a` and `f b`: why is it possible to write this way? I mean, why is it syntaсtic correct and compiles well?

I think there should be only one variable `(a -> b) -> a -> b` or `(a -> b) -> f -> f` or whatever `(a -> b) -> c -> d`

Once again, the question is not about the meaning of the function, but about being syntactic correct.

Comment: The buzzword is *higher kinded types* resp. *higher kinded type variables*

Comment: You are looking at type classes here. In particular, `fmap` is defined for the `Functor` type class. The book *Learn You a Haskell For Great Good* has very good explanations of type classes and Functors. There is even a free online version of the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `Type1 Type2` in Haskell means application of types. For example, you might have seen the type `Maybe Integer`. It works because `Maybe` is defined like this:

```
data Maybe a = ...
```

Note the type variable `a`. It means that we have to apply `Maybe` to some type before we can use it as a type itself. In `Maybe Integer`, this `a` is set to `Integer`.

Now in the question, we have `f a`, that is, a type variable is applied to another type variable. This means that `f` can be something like `Maybe` that expects to be applied to one more type, and `a` can be something like `Integer` that is a type in itself.

Comment: can `f` be a function which takes `a` as an argument?

Comment: @Marius: `f` is a **type variable**, so you have to instantiate it to a **type**. You cannot instantiate `f` to a function, because that would mix up the value-level with the type-level. If you want, you can think of `Maybe` as a **type function**, though.

Comment: @Toxaris That being said, you *can* instantiate f to be a function (e.g. see [`Functor ((->) r)`](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids))

Comment: @Julien I would say: "You can instantiate f to construct **function types**". There's a difference between "function" and "function type", and there's a another difference between `(->) r s` and `(->) r`.

Answer (score 7):

Do you accept the signature of the "normal" `map` function, `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`?

Now pretend that instead of `[a]` we had written `List a` (compare with `Maybe a`) so that the signature had read `map :: (a -> b) -> List a -> List b`. This signature is on the form `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` with `f = List`.

The function `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` is a generalisation of `map` to other type constructors like `Maybe`.

Comment: Do be careful with your type signatures: `fmap :: a -> b-> f a -> f b` is *not* the same as `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.

Comment: Thanks Julien! I obviously wasn't really awake.

Answer (score 4):

Well Haskell[1] type signatures are composed of 3 elements

- Type Variables.

  - They are implicitly universally quantified. Syntactically they start with lower case letters.
- Concrete Types.

  - They are the actual "stuff" that fills type variables. They start with upper case letters.
- The function arrow.

  - This represents, well, functions. It's curried and blah blah blah. Syntactically it's an arrow.

Now as for your example we have 2 elements. `a`, `b`, and `f` are type variables, and then we have the function arrow.

`a` and `b` have the kind `*`, meaning that they can be instantiated by concrete types as is. `f` on the other hand, has the kind `* -> *`[2]. That means that `f` can't be instantiated in the same way as `a` and `b`. It needs to be given instantiated with a type that takes a type of kind `*` and then yields a concrete type.

For example, `Maybe` has to be given another type, say `Int`, before you can construct a value of that type. Eg `Just 1 :: Maybe Int` but `wat :: Maybe` doesn't make sense. So the application `f a` is the same as applying a value-function `f` to a value `a`, except with types. You even have partial application!

So read `f a -> f b` as "a function which will take some type `f`, apply it to some type `a`, and return a value of type `f` applied to some type `b`".

[1] By Haskell I mean vanilla haskell. Type operators, rank N types, etc complicate things.

[2] This is *not* the normal function `->`. It's talking about types rather than values.

Comment: It might be helpful to squeeze in the definition of 'type constructor' along with the definition of kinds. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor#Type_constructor